# Refresh time notifcation android

Tags: android, time, notifications, refresh

I would like to add time on title notification. This time will be refreshed every second. Something along the lines of what is in Endomondo. How to do it without the effect of refreshing (blinking notification)

Comment: you mean like a sticky notification?

Comment: The idea is for me to refresh the data in the notification without using notify () which has the effect of "blinking"

Comment: you can use `AsyncTask` or `Timer`